# Accessing property of dynamic object when property name is a keyword

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

I am trying to access a property of a JSON object like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

dynamic myJsonData = JObject.Parse("{ \"out\":123, \"xyz\": 456 }");
Console.WriteLine(myJsonData.xyz); //works          
Console.WriteLine(myJsonData.out); //compiler error ";" expected
```

However, the last line does not compile.

Is there a simple way to use the dynamic property to get the value of "out" even though out is a keyword in C#?

Comment: use Console.WriteLine(myJsonData.@out);

Answer (score 8):

It should be solved by adding `@` before the reserved keyword:

```
Console.WriteLine(myJsonData.@out);
```

Here is a quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx):

> Keywords are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special
>   meanings to the compiler. They cannot be used as identifiers in your
>   program unless they include @ as a prefix. For example, @if is a valid
>   identifier but if is not because if is a keyword.

Comment: you're few mins faster